# Reactive Forms - Radio Button nested in a label

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a problem understanding why in one case Reactive Forms does not work as expected.

There is a button group with radio buttons in my template, each input is nested within a label.When I select a radio button the corresponding `FormControl` in my `FormGroup` gets no update.

When I place the input control outside the label everything works as expected.

What do I have to do to make this work for my example?

Here is the code:

*app.component.html :*

```html
<div [formGroup]="testForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn active">
          <input type="radio" value="0" name="regularity" formControlName="regularity" checked>
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <span>1 W</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn active">
          <input type="radio" value="1" name="regularity" >
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <span>2 W</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn active">
          <input type="radio" value="2" name="regularity" >
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <span>1 M</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn active">
          <input type="radio" value="3" name="regularity" >
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <span>3 M</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn active">
          <input type="radio" value="4" name="regularity" >
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <span>6 M</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn active">
          <input type="radio" value="5" name="regularity" >
          <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-2x"></i>
          <span>1 Y</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{testForm.value|json}}
```

*app.component.ts :*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private testForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.testForm = _fb.group({
      regularity: ''
    });
  }
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Edit:
Obviously there is a problem with using jQuery. When I remove jQuery from my .angular-cli.json, everything works.

Comment: why do you want to put the input inside the label ? you can use some thing like this <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" />

Comment: As I said. I found a good looking example here [link](http://codepen.io/BrianSassaman/pen/iLrpC) and I want to use this in my application. And as I am new to Angular it is important for me to understand things like this.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://plnkr.co/edit/8oSXK7tJH19KTjWG1u7M?p=preview) (there is only one `formControlName` directive, so only the first one works, but it does update....)

Comment: @n00dl3: You are right, I copied an already edited code. That's strange. In your plunker it's working, but in my environment not. I created my app with angular-cli and it's running with webpack.

Comment: which version of Angular are you running ? The fix might be to upgrade...

Comment: In my package.json everything related with angular is marked with "^4.0.0"

Comment: @n00dl3: When I remove "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" from .angular-cli.json, everything works. Is this a bug somewhere?

Comment: I doubt that cli has anything to do with that behavior, but note that using jQuery alongside with angular may lead to unpredictable behavior as jQuery assumes a "fixed" dom state, while angular updates the dom dynamically. Maybe you have some jQuery code somewhere that is messing with the dom of your inputs and screw the formControl behavior (for example replacing input elements).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I even used libraries like ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap but still the same behavior. Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @pantonis: Unfortunately not. I switched completely to angular material now.

Comment: You mean you are not using jquery anymore?

Comment: use formControlName instead of the optional "name" attribute AND Consider that 2-way binding does not exist when using reactive forms...

Answer (score 0):

**This might be your solution give the form control name to every control**[here you can find some extra stuff](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/RadioControlValueAccessor-directive.html)

```
      <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="beef" > Beef
      <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="lamb"> Lamb
      <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="fish"> Fish
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not best practise I did a temp workaround:

```
<label class="btn active" (click)="setValue('3')>
          <input type="radio" value="3" formControlName="regularity">
</label
```

and in typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private testForm: FormGroup;
  private regularity: FormControl

  ngOnInit(){
     this.buttonsPlatform = new FormControl();
     this.testForm= new FormGroup({
            regularity: this.regularity,
     });
   }

    title = 'app works!';

    public setValue(newValue) : void(){
       this.regularity.setValue(newValue);
    }
}
```